# Word or phrase for a rule or system so complex/vague/inconsistent that everyone is violating it

Tags: phrase-requests

X: **A policy, rule, standard or law so vague, complex, or inconsistent that nearly all entities subject to it are in violation of it.**

- Virtually every economic activity a person takes is somehow related to interstate commerce. (*The constitution's Interstate Commerce clause is an X*).
- The accusation of "bias" can virtually always be slung at one's opponent in an argument. There is a presumption that "bias" is inherently bad, when in fact bias is inherent in choice of words. (*All journalists are biased; the idea that journalism should be "unbiased" is an X*).

What is X?

Comment: The current term is "the administrative state," so complex that everyone can be found in violation of some regulation or the tax code.

Comment: Are those two examples the same? I don't see the commonality.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer, because it's really more idiomatic, but the policy/rule/law could be a *quagmire* (or *swamp*).

Comment: @Azor-Ahai The commonality is that both imply that a search will always find them because they are ever present.

Comment: @jpm but in one case, there might not be anything and in the other it's always there

Comment: @Azor-Ahai No, that is the entire point. The examples imply that it's always there for both. Whether this is the case in reality is one thing, but that's clearly the intended meaning.

Comment: @jpmc26 but I don't see how bias is related to a vague or complex system?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Bias is absolutely a complex issue. Consider that affirmative actions are considered bias by some and removing bias by others. It is not difficult to find something in a person's beliefs that can be cast in the light of a bias, even though one might deny that it is. The example could probably stand some improvement; I'll suggest an edit.

Answer (score 9):

A system of impenetrable complexity can be called "**byzantine**"

> - complex or intricate
> - characterized by elaborate scheming and intrigue, especially for the gaining of political power or favor

([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/byzantine))

To capture that this byzantine nature is intended, you could try "**obfuscatory**"

> - Tending to obfuscate; intended to conceal the truth by confusion.

([en.wiktionary.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation))

"I find these laws both byzantine and obfuscatory!" *[replaces monocle and harrumphs.]*

**EDIT:**

Your clarification is helpful! I think you're looking for a noun, but the best I can come up with is still an adjective: "**Kafkaesque**"

> - having a nightmarishly complex, bizarre, or illogical quality

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Kafkaesque))

As in: "The administrative state is Kafkaesque in its byzantine obfuscations."

Also, I agree with Xanne's comment that "The Administrative State" might be contemporarily sufficient, but that's probably too situational for what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks -- "byzantine" and "obfuscatory" are indeed useful for a subset, but not all, of the scenarios I seek to capture. I've revised my original question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

In legal terminology, these various adjectives when applied to a statute or regulation have somewhat different meanings. "Vague" means that the law has no definitive meaning that those subject to it can comprehend and so is defective. Ambiguous means that it has more than one definitive meaning and so is defective. "Complex" is not considered a legal defect. However, regulatory agencies sometimes will excuse violation of a complex regulation if they believe that there was no intent to violate.

Having spent a fair amount of my working life parsing federal regulations, they are seldom truly vague or ambiguous because of the process that they go through when being drafted under the Administrative Procedures Act (although emergency regulations may be vague or ambiguous). The real issue is that a normal citizen is highly unlikely to understand them due to their frequently technical focus, their plethora of internal references and stipulated definitions, and their implicit dependence on previous legal interpretations of their enabling statute and related regulations. The fact of the matter is that if you want a reliable answer to a question about a federal regulation, you probably need to ask a lawyer who specializes in the regulations that you are concerned about.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. My question is not specifically about the nature of Federal Regulations, however, but rather about rules in general in whatever context.

Answer (score 0):

There is the notion of an **open secret** that is somewhat related.  It refers to things that people are unwilling to publicly acknowledge, but everyone knows to be true.